# Compose: Create Text with Circle Background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Coming from SwiftUI, I wanted to create a view of a `Text` where it has a background of a Circle, where the circle's width/height grow as the text inside `Text` gets longer.

Since there's no `Circle()` in Compose like there is in `SwifUI`, I created just a `Spacer` instead and clipped it. The code below is using `ConstraintLayout` because I don't know how I would get the width of the `Text` in order to set the size of my `Circle` composable to be the same:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CircleDemo() {
    ConstraintLayout {
        val (circle, text) = createRefs()

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Black)
                .constrainAs(circle) {
                    centerTo(text)
                }
        )

        Text(
            text = "Hello",
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(text) {
                    centerTo(parent)
                }
        )
    }
}
```

I can use a `mutableStateOf { 0 }` where I update that in an `onGloballyPositioned` modifier attached to the `Text` and then set that as the `requiredSize` for the `Spacer`, but 1. that seems stupid and 2. the `Spacer` now draws outside the boundaries of the `ConstraintLayout`.

Visually I want to achieve this:

[image: A black circle with the word Hello entered inside]

How would I go about doing this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is also possible to use drawBehind from the modifier of the textView itself  such as below:

```
Text(
     modifier = Modifier
         .padding(16.dp)
         .drawBehind {
               drawCircle(
                    color = red,
                    radius = this.size.maxDimension
               )
          },
     text = "Hello",
)
```

of course, customize the radius and other properties as you wish!

[image]

Comment: Here the circle behind will be twice the size of the text and will overflow the Composable. The text maximum square size is given as the circle radius (instead of the circle diameter). If you want the circle to fit exactly the text size, then set: `radius = this.size.maxDimension / 2.0f`. Then you can add internal and external padding around the circle.

Answer (score 27):

You have to calculate the dimension of the background circle depending on the dimension of the text.
You can use a custom modifier based on [**`Modifier.layout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).layout(kotlin.Function3)):

```
fun Modifier.circleLayout() =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        // Measure the composable
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

        //get the current max dimension to assign width=height
        val currentHeight = placeable.height
        val currentWidth = placeable.width
        val newDiameter = maxOf(currentHeight, currentWidth)

        //assign the dimension and the center position
        layout(newDiameter, newDiameter) {
            // Where the composable gets placed
            placeable.placeRelative((newDiameter-currentWidth)/2, (newDiameter-currentHeight)/2)
        }
    }
```

Then just just apply it the `Text` with a background with a **`CircleShape`**:

```
    Text(
        text = "Hello World",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black, shape = CircleShape)
            .circleLayout()
            .padding(8.dp)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works well for longer strings like "Hello World" but I'm not sure what's needed to make it work for "1"

Comment: @Benoit Just assign a minSize to the `Text` element. For example  `.defaultMinSize(24.dp)`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti for small string is not working well, even giving minSize.

Answer (score 7):

```
@Composable
fun Avatar(color: Color) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(size.Dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(color = color),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello World")
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, what is size.Dp?  size isn't defined in your code.

Comment: This is perfect if the circle is the important object and the text ajust to it, for my case of use this is the right choise to go, the acepted answer calculate the circle in base of the text size so all circles will be diferent. In case of show them in a list, that result could be a problem.

Comment: hey @MartyMiller size.Dp could be 16.dp for instance

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @GabrieleMariotti's answer, you can combine the three modifiers into one, to make it easier to use.

```
/**
 * Draws circle with a solid [color] behind the content.
 *
 * @param color The color of the circle.
 * @param padding The padding to be applied externally to the circular shape. It determines the spacing between
 * the edge of the circle and the content inside.
 *
 * @return Combined [Modifier] that first draws the background circle and then centers the layout.
 */
fun Modifier.circleBackground(color: Color, padding: Dp): Modifier {
    val backgroundModifier = drawBehind {
        drawCircle(color, size.width / 2f, center = Offset(size.width / 2f, size.height / 2f))
    }

    val layoutModifier = layout { measurable, constraints ->
        // Adjust the constraints by the padding amount
        val adjustedConstraints = constraints.offset(-padding.roundToPx())

        // Measure the composable with the adjusted constraints
        val placeable = measurable.measure(adjustedConstraints)

        // Get the current max dimension to assign width=height
        val currentHeight = placeable.height
        val currentWidth = placeable.width
        val newDiameter = maxOf(currentHeight, currentWidth) + padding.roundToPx() * 2

        // Assign the dimension and the center position
        layout(newDiameter, newDiameter) {
            // Place the composable at the calculated position
            placeable.placeRelative((newDiameter - currentWidth) / 2, (newDiameter - currentHeight) / 2)
        }
    }

    return this then backgroundModifier then layoutModifier
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Text(
    text = "Hello World",
    color = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier
        .circleBackground(color = Color.DarkGray, padding = 6.dp)
)
```

[image: Text with circular background]

Answer (score 1):

Use a background drawable of a black circle inside a transparent color.  The background drawable will stretch to fill the view, and circles should stretch well without artifacting.

Comment: You should have added this as comment not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer marked as right is a little bit wrong. That because it calculates circle radius ... Actually it depends on many factors. You must take in mind:

1. Who is the Text parent ?
2. What Modifier does parent have ?
3. What Modifier does your Text have ?

Correct answer with easy customizable Circle can be that:

```
@Composable
fun CircleDemo() {
    // Initialize width as it is not exist
    val textWidthState: MutableState<Dp?> = remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
    val modifierWithCalculatedSize: State<Modifier> = 
    // You must provide new Modifier whenever width of Text is changed                                                                
        remember(textWidthState.value) {
            // Modifier for parent which draw the Circle
            val mod = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
            // Provide new Modifier only when calculation produces new value
            derivedStateOf {
                val currentWidth = textWidthState.value
                if (currentWidth != null) mod.size(currentWidth) else mod
            }
        }
    // Do not use Modifier with size(especially width) for Box. 
    Box(
        modifier = modifierWithCalculatedSize.value
             .clip(CircleShape),
         // Center your text inside Circle
         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
     ) {
         val density = LocalDensity.current
         Text(
             text = "Hello",
             color = Color.White,
             modifier = Modifier
                 // Obtain width of Text after position
                 .onGloballyPositioned {
                     textWidthState.value =  with(density) { 
                         it.size.width.toDp() 
                     }
                 }
                 // Adjust Circle size
                 .padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}
```