# How to make a circle shaped box which fits parent size compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a circle-shaped text that will fill all the available on the screen but still remain a circle. This is the code I've written for the component.

```
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .padding(4.dp)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clip(CircleShape),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "hello", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow))
}
```

And this is not the result I want it to be. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can apply the `aspectRatio(1f)` modifier to have `height` = `width` in the `Box`.

Something like:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(4.dp)
    .fillMaxSize()
    .aspectRatio(1f)
    .background(Color.Blue, shape = CircleShape),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(text = "hello", color= Yellow,   textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
}
```

[image]

If you want to have a better control of the Text composable you can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134006/compose-create-text-with-circle-background/67135525#67135525).