# Jetpack Compose custom Badge with dynamic text size with CircleShape is not drawn correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I had a BadgeView written with View using onMeasure, onLayout and OnDraw

[image]

I'm trying to migrate [this View](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/BadgeTextView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/badgetextview/BadgeTextView.kt) to Jetpack Compose.

Since drawing shapes is easier with compose i thought there is no need to use canvas or `Layout` functions at all, but size of Text or Surface wrapping it is not set properly before text size is calculated, and circle is not drawn properly.

Also checked out Badge component, it uses static sizes `BadgeWithContentRadius`, since in my design size depends on text size it's not possible to set a static size.

```
Surface(
    shape = CircleShape,
    contentColor = Color.White,
    color = Color.Red
) {
    Text(
        text = "0",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        fontSize = 34.sp,
    )
}
```

[image]

Then tried using

```
var size: Dp by remember { mutableStateOf(40.dp) }

val density = LocalDensity.current

Surface(
    shape = CircleShape,
    modifier = Modifier.size(size),
    contentColor = Color.Yellow,
    color = Color.Red
){
    Text(
        text = "0",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
            val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
            val circleRadius = textSize.width.coerceAtLeast(textSize.height)

            size = with(density) {
                circleRadius.toDp()
            }
            
            println("Size: $size")
        }
    )
}
```

Both of the implementations are not working, then tried doing it with `Layout`

```
@Composable
private fun Badge(text: String, badgeState: BadgeState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(shape = CircleShape, color = Color.Red, contentColor = Color.White) {
        BadgeLayout(text = text, badgeState = badgeState, modifier = modifier)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun BadgeLayout(text: String, badgeState: BadgeState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var circleRadius = 0
    var size: IntSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntSize(0, 0))
    }

    val content = @Composable {

        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
            fontSize = 34.sp,
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
                size = textLayoutResult.size
                circleRadius = size.width.coerceAtLeast(size.height)
            },
        )

    }

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }

        println(" Badge: $circleRadius, size: $size")
        layout(width = circleRadius, height = circleRadius) {
            placeables.first().placeRelative(0, 0)
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Shape seems to be applied correctly but couldn't find exact way to get text size to set number to center of Surface or Text.

How can a component, should have circle shape when it's one or digit number then turning it into RoundedCornerShape can be implemented with considering performance be implemented?

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67134006/compose-create-text-with-circle-background/67135525#67135525

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti with layout i'm doing what you provided in link you provided. But the issue is with positioning text in center of surface. What i get from `onTextLayout ` with `textLayoutResult.size` is size of `Text` i guess. I also need to get height and width of **text** so i can center it using radius and those dimensions.

Comment: how did you create this screen? is it using tabs in compose? i have similar kind of requirement.

Comment: @HeleenaJoy check out my answer. I posted the repo that you can find tabs and everything else. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143863/5457853

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've made the following modifier using [Modifier.layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).layout(kotlin.Function3)):

```
fun Modifier.badgeLayout() =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)

        // based on the expectation of only one line of text
        val minPadding = placeable.height / 4

        val width = maxOf(placeable.width + minPadding, placeable.height)
        layout(width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place((width - placeable.width) / 2, 0)
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
Text(
    text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.error, shape = CircleShape)
        .badgeLayout()
)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would look into using the Material Badge that is already available for Compose:

[Material Badge for Compose](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=pt#Badge(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1))

Comment: Do you mean `Badge`from `androidx.compose.material`? I already tried that, and it's nothing other than `Row` with `clip` and `.background( color = backgroundColor, shape = shape)`. It has a fixed size, it does not work with adjustable text size. `BadgeRadius = 4.dp`, `BadgeWithContentRadius = 8.dp`, and `BadgeContentFontSize = 10.sp`

Comment: You could have the size auto adjust by adjusting the scale modifier of the parent container that the text is located inside. How you adjust the scale factor depends on what you are scaling against (different screen densities, type of layout, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use textHeight with onTextLayout callback of `Text`. Since placeable.height returns full text height with font padding

```
   onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
                    textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                    //  This is text height without padding, result size returns height with font padding
                    textHeight = textLayoutResult.firstBaseline.toInt()

                }
```

Layout implementation is as

```
@Composable
fun Badge(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    badgeState: BadgeState = rememberBadgeState(),
) {
    BadgeComponent(badgeState = badgeState, modifier = modifier)
}

@Composable
private fun BadgeComponent(badgeState: BadgeState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    // TODO Question: Why does this not survive recompositions without mutableState?
    var textSize = remember { IntSize(0, 0) }
    var textHeight = remember(badgeState) { 0 }
    var badgeHeight = remember { 0 }

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val text = badgeState.text
    val isCircleShape = badgeState.isCircleShape

    val shape =
        if (isCircleShape) CircleShape else RoundedCornerShape(badgeState.roundedRadiusPercent)

    println(
        "✅ BadgeComponent: text: $text, " +
                "isCircleShape: $isCircleShape, " +
                "textHeight: $textHeight, " +
                "badgeHeight: $badgeHeight, " +
                "textSize: $textSize"
    )

    val content = @Composable {

        Text(
            text = badgeState.text,
            color = badgeState.textColor,
            fontSize = badgeState.fontSize,
            lineHeight = badgeState.fontSize,
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
                textSize = textLayoutResult.size
                //  This is text height without padding, result size returns height with font padding
                textHeight = textLayoutResult.firstBaseline.toInt()
                println("✏️ BadgeComponent textHeight: $textHeight, textSize: $textSize")
            },
        )
    }

    val badgeModifier = modifier
        .materialShadow(badgeState = badgeState)
        .then(
            badgeState.borderStroke?.let { borderStroke ->
                modifier.border(borderStroke, shape = shape)
            } ?: modifier
        )
        .background(
            badgeState.backgroundColor,
            shape = shape
        )

    Layout(
        modifier = badgeModifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }

        val placeable = placeables.first()

        if (badgeHeight == 0) {

            // Space above and below text, this is drawing area + empty space
            val verticalSpaceAroundText = with(density) {
                textHeight * .12f + 6 + badgeState.verticalPadding.toPx()
            }

            badgeHeight = (textHeight + 2 * verticalSpaceAroundText).toInt()
   
        if (isCircleShape) {

            // Use bigger dimension to have circle that covers 2 digit counts either
            badgeHeight = textSize.width.coerceAtLeast(badgeHeight)

            layout(width = badgeHeight, height = badgeHeight) {
                placeable.placeRelative(
                    (badgeHeight - textSize.width) / 2,
                    (badgeHeight - textSize.height) / 2
                )
            }
        } else {

            // Space left and right of the text, this is drawing area + empty space
            val horizontalSpaceAroundText = with(density) {
                textHeight * .12f + 6 + badgeState.horizontalPadding.toPx()
            }
            val width = (textSize.width + 2 * horizontalSpaceAroundText).toInt()

            layout(width = width, height = badgeHeight) {
                placeable.placeRelative(
                    x = (width - textSize.width) / 2,
                    y = (-textSize.height + badgeHeight) / 2
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also used custom Modifier and rememberable to set colored shadow, paddings, font properties, shapes and more which full implementation can be found in [github repository](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter4_state/BadgeComponent.kt).

Final result

[image]